# ionic 2 BluetoothSerial wont work

Tags: ionic2

I want to edit a program for sending informations via bluetooth, my source code is here, even if i try it on my device, it's still giving me "can't enable bluetooth".

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BluetoothSerial } from 'ionic-native';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

/*
Generated class for the BluetoothTracker provider.

 See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html
 for more info on providers and Angular 2 DI.
 */
 @Injectable()
 export class BluetoothTracker {

     constructor(public http: Http) {
         console.log('Hello BluetoothTracker Provider');
     }

     startConnection(){
        BluetoothSerial.isEnabled()
        .then(
             ( succes ) => { alert( "bluetooth enabled." ); },
             ( err ) => {
                BluetoothSerial.enable()
               .then(
               ( succes ) => { alert( "enabling bluetooth worked. " ); },
               ( err ) => { alert( "can't enable bluetooth. " ); }
              );
        }
      );
   }

 }
```

Comment: did you `alert(err)`?

Answer (score 0):

this is the solution, i have to use function BluetoothSerial.list(), to select bluetooth interface of my device, from where i want to send information.

```
  /** Select bluetooth interface from where i should be connected **/
BluetoothSerial.list().then(
  ( devices ) => { JSON.stringify( devices ); },
  ( err ) => { alert( " cant list devices" + err ); }
);
```